# Data model design assistance

Tags: mongodb

Looking for some insight on the best way to design this data model for a click tracking system.

Currently, this is how I am storing the data:

```
{
    "_id": "1a5be787-91bd-4ebc-99d1-fad750430da5",
    "time": {
        "$date": "2014-03-14T17:22:38.833Z"
    },
    "ip": "127.0.0.1",
    "user_agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.149 Safari/537.36",
    "referrer": null,
    "keyword": "test",
    "brand": "testing",
    "source": "google"
}
```

I pass their click via _id, so I pass this along to the page they're redirected to. When the user has completed out our form successfully (lead), I would like to know of this so what would be the best way to do this? Should I have a separate collection or should I update the document to store that data like this:

```
 {
        "_id": "1a5be787-91bd-4ebc-99d1-fad750430da5",
        "time": {
            "$date": "2014-03-14T17:22:38.833Z"
        },
        "ip": "127.0.0.1",
        "user_agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.149 Safari/537.36",
        "referrer": null,
        "keyword": "test",
        "brand": "testing",
        "source": "google",
        "lead": {
            success: 1,
            name: 'john',
            email: 'email@email.com'
        }


    }
```

Or would it be better to save that data in a new collection and reference the _id for the click?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The `_id` field itself is considered a primary key and therefore cannot have duplicates. If your need to group on "some identifier" the it is best to keep it in the same collection. But as the question stands it is currently "too broad" and could do with an edit to meet a specific case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: It depends.

From a logical point of view, you have to consider whether or not `Click` and `Lead` are different business objects, or the same business object in different states. When they are different BOs, it would be a reason to put them into different collections. When they are the same BO, they would be in the same collection.

From a technical point of view you need to consider how your queries look.

I assume (blindly) that you will have magnitudes more `Click`s than `Lead`s. I further assume (even more blindly) that you will do a lot more querying (and different querying) on the `Lead` objects. For that reason it would be useful to put the `Lead` documents into a separate collection, because this speeds up indexing and vastly speeds up any non-indexed queries (which you might have to do anyway, because data-mining isn't one of MongoDBs strong points).

But on the other hand, all native MongoDB operations can only be performed on a single collection. When you need a query which requires both `Click`s and `Lead`s (like counting which referrer has which lead/click ratio), you will have to do multiple queries and do the data-mining on the application-layer (but chances are that you will have to do most of your data-mining outside of the database anyway, because data-mining isn't one of MongoDBs strong-points)